# Supabase subscribe, single row, two columns

Tags: subscribe, supabase

I'm trying to subscribe to a particular table row via the supabasejs library. It works for a single row like so:

```
supabase
    .channel('any')
    .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: '*', table:'SomeTable', filter: 'id=eq.'+x}, payload => {
      console.log('Change received for row:' + x, payload)
    })
    .subscribe()
```

But, i'd like instead to look for when id=x AND somecolumn=y... like so, perhaps:

```
supabase
    .channel('any')
    .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: '*', table:'SomeTable', filter: ('id=eq.'+i,'somecolumn=eq.'+x)}, payload => {
      console.log('Change received for row:' + i, payload)
    })
    .subscribe()
```

I have also tried:

```
supabase
    .channel('any')
    .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: '*', table:'SomeTable', filter: supabase.and('id=eq.'+i,'somecolumn=eq.'+x)}, payload => {
      console.log('Change received for row:' + i, payload)
    })
    .subscribe()
```

But, that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: As it turns out this doesn't work either: ```supabase
    .channel('any')
    .on('postgres_changes', { event: '*', schema: '*', table:'SomeTable', filter: 'id=eq.'+i, filter:'somecolumn=eq.'+x}, payload => {
      console.log('Change received for row:' + i, payload)
    })
    .subscribe()``` -- it just listens to the 2nd filter.

Comment: Currently having two `eq` filter is not supported on Supabase realtime. You can apply one filter, and check for the other filter on your client side.